# Create a link but don't change the canonical path

Tags: shell, symlink, cd-command

In each users' directory there exists a symbolic link to `/var/www/website/public_html/`. However, whenever a user `cd`s into the link, he sees the path as `/home/username/public_html/`. Is there any way to link to a directory however when the user changes into the directory, the command `pwd` will show the canonical or real path to the directory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what Stephane said, you can also use `set -o physical` to do this by default in `bash`.

Answer (score 2):

That's a *feature* of modern shells (the Bourne shell and original csh (and probably the original Almquist shell as well) were not affected). Use `cd -P` to work around it:

```
cd -P public_html
```

You can make that the default with

```
alias cd='cd -P'
```

POSIXly, or as Chris said:

```
set -o physical
```

in bash or zsh or

```
setopt chaselinks
```

in zsh or

```
set symlinks = chase
```

in tcsh.

Comment: Thank you Stephane. (Is that pronounced `stef-an` or `stef-an-e`?) I think that I'm familiar with [this type of feature](http://crossthebreeze.files.wordpress.com/2007/08/feature.jpg)!